# The mysql fetch results are empty if I retrieve all rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some issues returning values from a server with php + mysql.

This is my code

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Nicknames", $con);

    if (mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Create']) == "NICKNAME") {
        $output;        
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($row['Taken'] == '0')  $output = $output . $row['Nickname'] . ",";
        }
        echo substr($output, 0, -1);

    }
```

If I add break; in the while loop, it works perfectly and I just get 1 row of my table.
If instead I want to return all 3000 rows, I just get an empty answer from the server.

If the table has 10 rows it works.

I was wondering if it is about the amount of rows, or it is because eventual special characters.

thanks

**UPDATE**
It works until 1330 rows, if I try to get more, I get an empty result

```
$counter = 0;       
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($row['Taken'] == '0')  $output = $output . $row['Nickname'] . ",";
            if ($counter == 1330) break;
            $counter++;
        }
        echo substr($output, 0, -1);
```

Comment: Can you post your SQL query too so we can see how you're actually querying the database?

Comment: Also: are you sure each $row['Taken'] is always ascii char 0?

Comment: I think problem in time execution of scripts.

Comment: @Nick Shaw  yeah I'm sure.  I've added the SQL query to the question. As I said before, it works perfectly for few lines, but not when I want to retrieve all 3000 rows.

Comment: Try do an echo in the while-loop instead of saving the value. The $output may be too large to display it. Troubleshot to see if LIMIT 100 and LIMIT 1000 works.

Comment: @Robin Castlin Indeed, this is what I've done. Check my updated answer, thanks.

Comment: What should I do to allow larger results ?

Comment: "I was wondering if it is about the amount of rows, or it is because eventual special characters." This can be confirmed through ordering differently, for instance ORDER BY RAND() and see if it still get stuck at 1330.

Comment: @Robin Castlin Great man, it was a special character indeed. Thanks, if you post your answer I can accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the middle of your table's rows there may have been an invalid character.

Since you know which row it stops working at, try running the SELECT with different ORDER BY's to determine if this is the case. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried showing error messages?

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
  ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

It is possible that $output is filling the memory_limit before getting to your echo, and if display_errors is false, you won't see the error stating out of memory.

Comment: I've tried and I don't get any error. Also, the memory limit is currently 96M. I guess more than enough for 3000 rows with only text, correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too obvious, but ... 
Have you checked the max_execution_time value in your php.ini ?

Maybe the script is dying before finishing the 3000 rows fetch.

Try setting

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

at the beginning of the script to avoid this problem

Comment: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons

Answer (score -1):

`$output` after the if condition should be `$output = "";`